# print number of next page

Tags: page-numbering, calculations

I know I can use `\thepage` to print the current page number in my document. But is it possible to print the number of the next page, e.g. for phrases like "continue on page "?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, even without the use of any extra packages. Just write a small makro in the preamble of your document like this:

```
\newcommand{\thenextpage}{
    \number\numexpr\thepage+1\relax
}
```

Then use `\thenextpage` anywhere in your document to print the number of the next page.

Comment: What happens when `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}`?

Comment: @Werner `\newcommand*{\thenextpage}{\begingroup\addtocounter{page}{1}\thepage\addtocounter{page}{-1}\endgroup}` works with Roman page numbers. But, the main problem is usually that the page number is not known in advance because of the asynchronous output routine. Therefore, this will only work in a reliable way, if the location is somewhat known, e.g. at the start of a chapter or right after a `\clearpage`.

Comment: Useful macro. I used the idea to hyperlink to a page number in an external PDF. The external PDF files were chapters 1.pdf to 12.pdf of a book. Here's the modified macro and how it was used with hyperref for the book link. Thanks to  LukeLP and Heiko Oberdiek:

    `\def\frontmattercount{1}
    \newcommand{\mygetpagerefnumber}[1]{% #1=LaTeX label
    \number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{#1}+\frontmattercount\relax
    }`
   


    `\newcommand{\booklink}[1]{\relax% CTAN pkg hyperref
    \href{1.pdf\#page=\mygetpagerefnumber{#1}}{\pageref*{#1}}\relax
    }`

Answer (score 8):

Page numbering (displaying and referencing) should typically be handled using `\label`s and `\ref`s. Here's an example showing why `\thepage` is not always accurate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] \texttt{Page: \thepage}% On page 1, displays as "Page: 1"

\lipsum[5-7] \texttt{Page: \thepage}% On page 2, displays as "Page: 1"

\end{document}
```

The correct output is displayed when using the `\label`-`\ref` system:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] \label{pg:one}\texttt{Page: \pageref{pg:one}}% On page 1, displays as "Page: 1"

\lipsum[5-7] \label{pg:two}\texttt{Page: \pageref{pg:two}}% On page 2, displays as "Page: 2"

\end{document}
```

The above example works regardless of the representation of the `page` counter (given by `\thepage`). For example, one can only perform calculations on `\thepage` if it expands to a number (via `\arabic{page}`, typically). It would not be possible to use `\thepage` within the `\frontmatter` of a `book` or `report`, since then `\thepage` defaults to `\roman{page}`.

If you really want to perform calculations on the page number, use the `\label`-`\ref` system together with [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] \label{pg:one}\texttt{Page: \pageref{pg:one}}% On page 1, displays as "Page: 1"

\lipsum[5-7] \texttt{Page: \number\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{pg:one}+1\relax}% On page 2, displays as "Page: 2"

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using a `longtable` which expands onto multiple pages. The last row of that `longtable` should state "continue on page xx" (the next page). I can't label any of the pages, since there's just one `longtable` environment, and even if I could, I wouldn't want to check where a new page begins, assign them a label each, and manually add a row to my table referring that label. There has to be some kind of automation, isn't it?

Comment: @LukeLR: Why not just write "continued on next page"?

Comment: In German, I wouldn't use any equivalent to "continued on next page". At least in my opinion, naming the page number is better german. It's just a detail, but I thought it should be possible.

Comment: @LukeLR: The use of this application in [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) is not recommended (see [the discussion between myself and the package author in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35159258#35159258)). If you're interested in a `longtable`-specific solution, perhaps consider asking a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).

Comment: Okay, I'll consider that. Thanks a lot for your efforts!

Comment: @Werner your macro is not useful in frontmatter, for the pages numbered in roman. It gives the error `! Missing number, treated as zero.`